# web performance and load testing vs2010

Tags: database, performance, load

i m getting this issue when created a web test and run this for load test

The load test results database could not be opened.  Check that the load test results database specified by the connect string for your test controller (or local machine) specifies a database that contains the load test schema and that is currently available.  For more information, see the Visual Studio help topic 'About the Load Test Results Store'.   The connection error was: An error occurred while attempting to create the load test results repository schema: To create the database 'LoadTest2010' your user account must have the either the SQL Server 'sysadmin' role or both the 'serveradmin' and 'dbcreator' roles

please help me out of this

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here is that you permissions are not right for the account that you are  using to run the load test. What account? That depends on whether you are running a controller and agents or if you are just running your load test locally in Visual Studio or MSTest.

In the latter case, make sure that the credentials you use to log in to your Visual Studio/MSTest machine will allow you to also create a database on your SQL Server.

If you are using a controller and agents, the user credentials that you enter into your Controller configuration tool must have those same permissions.

You've probably read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243155.aspx) before. Read it again and then adjust your user permissions or get your Sysadmin to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

To resolve this issue, I followed the below steps:

1. Open VS command prompt in elevated mode (Run As Administrator)
2. Run the command "cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
   10.0\Common7\IDE"
3. Run the command "SQLCMD /S localhost\sqlexpress /i
   loadtestresultsrepository.sql "